# Parsing XML with python and xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to take xml data from the BambooHR api and then create users in our company google account. Right now I am struggling to get through the xml. Every example I have seen has data with different tag names where mine are the same('field) but have an ID attached to them

Here's my xml response

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<directory>
 <fieldset>
  <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
  <field id="firstName">First name</field>
  <field id="lastName">Last name</field>
  <field id="preferredName">Preferred name</field>
  <field id="jobTitle">Job title</field>
  <field id="mobilePhone">Mobile Phone</field>
  <field id="workEmail">Work Email</field>
  <field id="department">Department</field>
  <field id="location">Location</field>
  <field id="division">Division</field>
  <field id="linkedIn">LinkedIn URL</field>
  <field id="supervisor">Manager</field>
  <field id="photoUploaded">Employee photo</field>
  <field id="photoUrl">Photo URL</field>
  <field id="canUploadPhoto">Can Upload Photo</field>
 </fieldset>
 <employees>
  <employee id="379">
   <field id="displayName">test one</field>
   <field id="firstName">test</field>
   <field id="lastName">one</field>
   <field id="preferredName"></field>
   <field id="jobTitle">Assistant</field>
   <field id="mobilePhone">123456789</field>
   <field id="workEmail">test.one@email.com</field>
   <field id="department">Recruitment</field>
   <field id="location">Remote</field>
   <field id="division">company name</field>
   <field id="linkedIn"></field>
   <field id="supervisor">test supervisor</field>
   <field id="photoUploaded">true</field>
   <field id="photoUrl">"https://image.com"</field>
   <field id="canUploadPhoto">yes</field>
  </employee>
  <employee id="398">
   <field id="displayName">tester two</field>
   <field id="firstName">tester</field>
   <field id="lastName">two</field>
   <field id="preferredName"></field>
   <field id="jobTitle">Recruitment</field>
   <field id="mobilePhone">987654321</field>
   <field id="workEmail">tester.two@company.com</field>
   <field id="department">Recruitment</field>
   <field id="location">Remote</field>
   <field id="division">company</field>
   <field id="linkedIn"></field>
   <field id="supervisor">test supervisor</field>
   <field id="photoUploaded">true</field>
   <field id="photoUrl">"https://image.com"</field>
   <field id="canUploadPhoto">yes</field>
  </employee>
 </employees>
</directory>
```

Here's some code Ive been working on. I pass the function an xml file I have created and saved locally after I pull it from the api

```
def parse_XML(xml_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    print('printing root....')
    print(root.tag, root.attrib) #directory {}

    for emp in root.iter('employee'):
        for employee in emp:
            #if employee work email == '':
                # get all users data ready to send to google to create a new account
```

So im trying to see if the users work email is == "" which means they dont have a google account and then I will send the users info to google to create an account

the problem ive ran into is since the tags are all the same Im having trouble getting the value of the tags

If you can help make all the users into a list of employees or recommend the best way to accomplish this that would be great. Or ask questions and I can try to specify things

Comment: `for emp in root.iter('employee')` already iterates over all `<employee>` nodes. What do you expect `for employee in emp` to do?

Comment: for emp in root.iter('employee')  will iterate over all the employees, Should I not loop over all the field attributes an employee has? can I just access each field from 'emp'

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for emp in root.iter('employee')` already iterates over all the `<employee>` nodes. All you have left to do is iterate all the `<field>` nodes and check if the content of the `workEmail` field is empty:

```py
for emp in root.iter('employee'):
    for field in emp.iter('field'):
        if field.attrib['id'] == 'workEmail' and field.text == '':
            print('this employee has no email')
```

UPDATE: Since you are interested in few specific `<field>` nodes it may be beneficial to use xpath to get the ones you need instead of the inner loop:

```py
for emp in root.iter('employee'):
    email = emp.find('field[@id="workEmail"]').text
    if email == '':
        first_name = emp.find('field[@id="firstName"]').text
        last_name = emp.find('field[@id="lastName"]').text
        # do whatever with these details
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. Also I tried to see if email == "" and it didn't work but it did work when I used email == None